# How to calculate steps using STEP_COUNT_SENSOR in xamarin forms for android

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to calculate  step count while walking in xamarin forms for android? Please help me Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dependenceService to achieve that, First of all, we should create a interface for it.

```
 public interface IStepCounter
{
    int Steps { get; set; }

    bool IsAvailable();

    void InitSensorService();

    void StopSensorService();
}
```

Then achieve it in the android platform.

```
 [assembly: Dependency(typeof(StepCounter))]
 namespace App64.Droid
 {
public class StepCounter : Java.Lang.Object, IStepCounter, ISensorEventListener
{

        private int StepsCounter = 0;
        private SensorManager sManager;

        public int Steps
        {
            get { return StepsCounter; }
            set { StepsCounter = value; }
        }

        public new void Dispose()
        {
            sManager.UnregisterListener(this);
            sManager.Dispose();
        }

        public void InitSensorService()
        {

            sManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.SensorService) as SensorManager;

            sManager.RegisterListener(this, sManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.StepDetector), SensorDelay.Fastest);
        }

        public void OnAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, [GeneratedEnum] SensorStatus accuracy)
        {


        Console.WriteLine("OnAccuracyChanged called");
        }

        public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
        {
        StepsCounter ++;



            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        public void StopSensorService()
        {
            sManager.UnregisterListener(this);
        }

    public bool IsAvailable()
    {
        return Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.HasSystemFeature(Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.FeatureSensorStepCounter) && Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.HasSystemFeature(Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.FeatureSensorStepDetector);
    }
}
```

}

In the end use it in the xamarin forms.
`Mainpage.xaml`

```
  <StackLayout>
    <Label x:Name="mylabel"/>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Button Text="click" Clicked="Button_Clicked" x:Name="myBtn" IsVisible="False"/>
</StackLayout>
```

`Mainpage.xaml.cs`

```
     [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (DependencyService.Get<IStepCounter>().IsAvailable())
        {
            DependencyService.Get<IStepCounter>().InitSensorService();

            myBtn.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            mylabel.Text = DependencyService.Get<IStepCounter>().Steps.ToString();



    }
}
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]